# Conditional libraries in build.sbt

Tags: sbt

Using buildsbt. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if (condition) {
  libraryDependencies += ... // library from maven
}
else {
  unmanagedJars in Compile += ... // local library instead
}
```

However, build.sbt doesn't like this at all. I've been able to accomplish this using side effects, but that's obviously undesirable. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```scala
val additionalLibraryDependencies = Seq(...)
val additionalUnmanagedJars  = Seq(...)

libraryDependencies ++=(
  if (condition) {
    additionalLibraryDependencies
  }
)

unmanagedJars in Compile ++= (
  if (!condition) {
    additionalUnmanagedJars
  }
)
```

To set the condition from command line you should add the following lines:

```scala
val someValueFromCommandLine = System.getProperty("key.of.the.value", "false")
if (someValueFromCommandLine.equals("true")){
    ...
}
```

You can pass it like `sbt -Dkey.of.the.value=true`

Comment: how do you set or unset `condition` on the command line so you can use one set of libs or another based on something like a maven profile?

Answer (score 1):

This might be easier to do using a `Build.scala` build definition.

Here is an example build.sbt file (this is optional):

```scala
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1101-jdbc41",
   "redis.clients" % "jedis" % "2.5.2"
)
```

Then create another file `your_project_home/project/Build.scala`

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

object BuildSettings {
    val condition = false

    val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
        version := "1.0.0",
        if(condition) libraryDependencies ++= Seq("commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.9")
        else unmanagedJars in Compile += file("/tmp/nil")
    )
}

object MyBuild extends Build {
    import BuildSettings._
    lazy val root: Project = Project("root", file("."), settings = buildSettings)
}
```

Your project structure should look like this:

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   └── Build.scala
└── target
```

You can make the "condition" to be whatever what you need (here I just set it to false). The libraryDependencies defined inside `build.sbt` will always be included. The ones defined in `Build.scala` will depend on the "condition."

Verify that everything works as expected from the command line using:

```
sbt "inspect libraryDependencies"
```