# Cannot import sbt._ or Keys._ to Build.scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to workout a conditional libraries set-up for a single project/module in a multi-project build.  This one module needs to have a conditional dependency list to load a locally stored jar dependency for either a development or production environment.  From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337672/conditional-libraries-in-build-sbt) and this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193795/how-to-add-environment-profile-config-to-sbt), it seems that replacing the build.sbt file with a Build.scala file for this module is the best route.  However, when I do the `import sbt._` and `import Keys._` I get a `Cannot resolve symbol Keys` warning from IntelliJ.  I am able to do the import calls in the various other build.sbt files, but they do not resolve in any of the .scala files.